# Auctex align-current does not properly align table in Aquamacs - what's wrong?

Tags: auctex, fonts, align, aquamacs

I'm working with very large tables (14 columns for example) and it's really difficult to find the right cell to edit.

I discovered the `align-current` command and tried to use it on my table, but the result is still not very helpful: In Aquamacs, it looks like that:

[image]

- the red signs are the "&" characters, which separate the table columns. Ideally they should be placed on straight vertical lines, but you can see that they don't in my case

However, if I copy the text into another text editor, it looks properly aligned:

[image]

I wonder if it is a problem with the font used in emacs, `describe-font` in my .tex buffer gives

name (opened by): -apple-Monaco-medium-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Monaco
            size: 12
          height: 17
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0

I thought that Monaco is a monospaced font, so that should not be the problem, or could it?

Comment: Doesn't look monospaced in your screenshot.  Switch to one you're sure is monospaced in order to check.

Comment: Monaco *is* a monospaced font, but the font in your screenshot doesn't look like Monaco (specifically the OSX typeface designed by Kare and Holmes). The `i`s and `l`s in your screenshot do not have serifs, making them thinner than other letters.

Comment: @Dan : thanks, you both were right! Aquamacs seems to have its own font definitions by default. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @Dan and @Matthew Piziak for your help!

Indeed, Aquamacs seems to have its own font definitions:

> **Switching to a mono-spaced (fixed pitch) font throughout**
>   Aquamacs uses a mono-spaced font (Monaco) as a default, but uses the system’s
>   variable-width font (Lucida Grande) for all text modes, including
>   those derived from ‘text-mode’.
>
> To use a monospaced font throughout (or the same font everywhere),
>   just disable ‘aquamacs-autoface-mode’ by selecting Options →
>   Appearance → Auto Faces → Auto Faces. Save your options. You may then
>   choose another font via Options → Appearance → Font if you so desire.
>
> Alternatively, if you would just like to customize specific fonts, see
>   the next frequently asked question.

source: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#toc10

I did as described and disabled the `autoface-mode` and after a restart of Aquamacs, the table looks really aligned:

[image]